# Джанго ManyToMany Фильтр

Tags: django, many-to-many

```
from django.db import models


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='student_of')
```

Как получить студентов, посещающих несколько одинаковых курсов?
Когда я делаю запрос подобно этому, я получаю пустой queryset

Example Query

```
courses = Student.objects.filter(
    Q(courses__id=<id1>)  & Q(courses__id=<id2>)
).distinct()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык; 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)